# How to add mixed Text and XElements on XElement value

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am trying to add as value to an `XElement` mixed text and inline elements.

For example when setting the string `"this is a mixed text <foo>and</foo> inline element."` the `XElement.Nodes` to be able to return the text node as `XmlNodeType.Text` & the element as `XmlNodeType.Element`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use e.g. `new XElement("parent", "this is a mixed text ", new XElement("foo", "and"), " inline element.")` respectively `element.Add("this is a mixed text ", new XElement("foo", "and"), " inline element.")`.

If you have a plain string then use e.g.

```
element.Add(XElement.Parse("<root>" + "this is a mixed text <foo>and</foo> inline element." + "</root>").Nodes());
```

Comment: @NickT, you can use `XElement.Parse` with a dummy wrapper element in that case.

Comment: I use something like XElement.Parse("<temp>" + myString + "</temp>"); and it works!